# Fixed Position AWeber Form in iOS7 Safari - Quirks Mode?

Tags: javascript, ios, css, aweber

Hi: I'm working on a landing page with an AWeber lightbox form, intended to be optimized for smartphones, specifically iPhones. It's here:

http://www.radionowheremusic.com/mobilebox.html

If I visit this page on an iPhone 5, and click the "Download Music" button, everything looks fine. However, when I click the Name or Email field and try to enter my information, ofter the phone keyboard appears, the AW form snaps back to the center of the screen and I can't see the  name or address I'm inputting.

I'm not a very experienced programmer (at all), and from some googling around, I'm guessing this is related to quirks mode CSS? Is that right? In any case, if someone can tell me what's up, and what I might try to fix the problem, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I should also note that this doesn't happen on a desktop, in either Safari or Chrome. If I launch the lightbox and then resize the desktop browser window, the lightbox stays fixed in its original spot no matter what you do with the browser window.

Comment: Oops - one more note: the same problem is occurring in both Safari and Chrome on the iPhone.

Comment: Okay, never mind on this - I've decided to trash the whole lightbox idea.